# Overriding the default constructor when creating a deepcopy in Python

Tags: python, class, object, oop, copy

Let's say I have this class (simplified for the sake of clarity):

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, creator_id):
        self._id = get_unique_identifier()
        self._owner = creator_id
        self._members = set()
        self._time = datetime.datetime.now()
        get_creator(creator_id).add_foo(self._id)
    def add_member(self, mbr_id):
        self._members.add(mbr_id)
```

and I want to make a `__deepcopy__()` method for it. From what I can tell, the way that these copies are generally made is to create a new instance using the same constructor parameters as the old one, however in my case, that will result in a different identifier, a different time, and a different member set, as well as the object being referenced by the creator's object twice, which will result in breakages.

One possible workaround would be to create the new instance then modify the incorrect internal data to match, but this doesn't fix the issues where the new object's ID will still be present in the creator's data structure. of course, that could be removed manually, but that wouldn't be clean or logical to follow.

Another workaround is to have an optional `copy_from` parameter in the constructor, but this would add complexity to the constructor in a way that could be confusing, especially since it would only be used implicitly by the object's `__deepcopy__()` method. This still looks like the best option if there isn't a better way.

```py
#...
def __init__(self, creator_id, copy_from=None):
    if isinstance(copy_from, Foo):
         # copy all the parameters manually
         pass
    else:
         # normal constructor
         pass
#...
```

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to the copy constructor in C++, where I can get a reference to the original object and then copy across its parameters without having to add unwanted complexity to the original constructor.

Any ideas are appreciated. Let me know if I've overlooked something really simple.

Comment: I don't think its possible to create a memory copy of an object without creating a new object. If that was possible then things like static instance counters in class won't have been accurate.

Comment: I mean I am looking to create a new object, just I want it to have exactly the same properties as the original, including those that are generated upon creation of the original.

Comment: Create an empty object using `obj = object.__new__(Foo)` then just copy the instance attributes, `vars(obj).update(vars(self))` this should cover most cases

Comment: First, your understanding of how deep copies work is incorrect - the `copy` module has no way to recover the constructor parameters used to create an object, if a constructor was involved at all. Second, it doesn't sound like it makes sense to copy one of these objects at all. It'd break stuff like the uniqueness of the "unique" identifiers.

Comment: I'm not looking to recover constructor parameters, the impression I got was that the `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()` methods were supposed to return a new copy of the object. As such, I want a way to then manually copy the attributes across from the existing object (where the __deepcopy__() method is called) to the new one. I mainly get copies of the data structures for the purposes of getting and setting the state of the program. If I don't deep-copy the data, then future modifications to it will also update any previous copies of the state that I got.

Comment: You may not be looking to recover constructor parameters, but your mistaken idea of how deep copies work would *require* the `copy` module to recover the original constructor parameters to construct the new object - "From what I can tell, the way that these copies are generally made is to create a new instance using the same constructor parameters as the old one".

Comment: Why are you trying to implement `__deepcopy__` at all? The default deepcopy mechanism usually does the job fine, and if it doesn't, the details of how it fails are crucial for fixing the failure (or for concluding that the operation doesn't make sense).

Comment: "From what I can tell, the way that these copies are generally made is to create a new instance using the same constructor parameters as the old one". By this I meant the way that the developer would construct the copy, not the way that `deepcopy()` would do so. Can `deepcopy()` actually make copies of objects that don't have a `__deepcopy__()` method defined?

Comment: Have you tried juanpa's comment?

Comment: I'm working on it right now :)

Comment: "Can `deepcopy()` actually make copies of objects that don't have a `__deepcopy__()` method defined?" - yes, usually. `copy.deepcopy` is hacky and fragile, but in a way where the best option (besides avoiding it entirely) is usually to let it do its thing unless and until a specific problem comes up.

Comment: Anything that can be pickled can be deepcopied I think.

Comment: (Also, juanpa.arrivillaga's comment implements a shallow copy.)

Comment: Yes, it won't deepcopy "object of object" types of structure.